# Moshi: How to Deserialize JSON with a mix of fixed and dynamic properties

Tags: java, json, kotlin, unmarshalling, moshi

For a JSON like this consider the properties other than `attributes` are dynamic:

```json
"records": [
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "...",
      "url": "..."
    },
    "Id": "...",
    "Name": "...",
    "...": "..."
  }
]
```

How can I Desrialize or Unmarshall into a Dataclass like this such that all the dynamic keys go into a `recordBody: Map<String, Any>`

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Body(
  val records: List<Record>,
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Record(
  val attributes: Attributes,
  val recordBody: Map<String, Any>
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Attributes(
  val type: String,
  val url: String
)
```

I cannot find an annotation similar to `@JsonAnySetter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current answer assumes that the "attributes" property will always be the first property and that the recordBody map values are always strings (that doesn't seem to be the case in the original question?), and it also could use the `selectName` and other Moshi JsonReader features.

Here's my take on a more resilient adapter.

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Body(
  val records: List<Record>
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Record(
  val attributes: Attributes,
  val recordBody: Map<String, Any>
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Attributes(
  val type: String,
  val url: String
)

object RecordAdapter {
  val options = JsonReader.Options.of("attributes")

  @FromJson
  fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader, attributesJsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Attributes>): Record {
    reader.beginObject()
    var attributes: Attributes? = null
    val recordBody = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      when (reader.selectName(options)) {
        0 -> {
          if (attributes != null) {
            throw JsonDataException("Duplicate attributes.")
          }
          attributes = attributesJsonAdapter.fromJson(reader)
        }

        -1 -> {
          recordBody[reader.nextName()] = reader.readJsonValue()!!
        }

        else -> {
          throw AssertionError()
        }
      }
    }
    reader.endObject()
    return Record(attributes!!, recordBody)
  }

  @ToJson
  fun toJson(
    writer: JsonWriter,
    value: Record,
    attributesJsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Attributes>,
    dynamicJsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Any>
  ) {
    writer.beginObject()
    writer.name("attributes")
    attributesJsonAdapter.toJson(writer, value.attributes)
    for (entry in value.recordBody.entries) {
      writer.name(entry.key)
      dynamicJsonAdapter.toJson(writer, entry.value)
    }
    writer.endObject()
  }
}

fun main() {
  val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(RecordAdapter).build()
  val idResponseJsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Body::class.java)
  val encoded = """
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "attributes": {
          "type": "...",
          "url": "..."
        },
        "Id": "...",
        "Name": "...",
        "...": "..."
      }
    ]
  }""".trimIndent()
  val decoded = Body(
    listOf(
      Record(
        Attributes(
          type = "...",
          url = "..."
        ),
        mapOf(
          "Id" to "...",
          "Name" to "...",
          "..." to "..."
        )
      )
    )
  )
  println(idResponseJsonAdapter.fromJson(encoded))
  println(idResponseJsonAdapter.toJson(decoded))
}
```

Prints:

```
Body(records=[Record(attributes=Attributes(type=..., url=...), recordBody={Id=..., Name=..., ...=...})])
{"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"...","url":"..."},"Id":"...","Name":"...","...":"..."}]}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric Cochran. This is indeed robust. I have a doubt, what is the difference between extending `JsonAdapter<Record>` vs not extending and just using the annotations `@FromJson` and `@ToJson`. I see both work alike. When is what recommended?

Comment: You don't need the annotations if you extend JsonAdapter yourself, but Moshi creates a JsonAdapter.Factory for you if you use the annotations. You can make your own without the annotations, but it's just more user code, especially when you're doing things like delegating to other JsonAdapters like in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Custom Moshi Marshaller to achieve this:

```kotlin
class RecordAdapterFactory : JsonAdapter<Record>() {
  @FromJson
  override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Record {
    reader.beginObject()
    var attributes = Attributes("", "")
    val recordBody = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      when (val nextName = reader.nextName()) {
        "attributes" -> {
          val attrMap = reader.readJsonValue() as Map<String, String>
          attributes = Attributes(attrMap["type"] ?: "", attrMap["url"] ?: "")
        }
        else -> recordBody[nextName] = reader.nextString()
      }
    }
    reader.endObject()
    return Record(attributes, recordBody)
  }

  @ToJson
  override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, record: Record?) {
    writer.beginObject()
    writer.name("attributes")
    writer.beginObject()
    writer.name("type").value(record?.attributes?.type)
    writer.name("url").value(record?.attributes?.url)
    writer.endObject()
    record?.recordBody?.entries?.forEach { writer.name(it.key).value(it.value) }
    writer.endObject()
  }
}
```